# MySQL XML load having unexpected results between local and online file

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm trying to load part of a XML file into my MySQL database on localhost.
My table create query is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vacations`(
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`region` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`startdate` date NOT NULL,
`enddate` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The xml file is located here:
http://opendata.rijksoverheid.nl/v1/sources/rijksoverheid/infotypes/schoolholidays?output=xml

I also copied the text on that page and saved it in a LOCAL xml file.

Now when I fill my table with the following query useing the ONLINE xml file

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'http://opendata.rijksoverheid.nl/v1/sources/rijksoverheid/infotypes/schoolholidays?output=xml' 
INTO TABLE vacations
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<vacation>'
```

My table will be filled with the following data:

`('schoolvakanties', 'zuid', '2013-10-11', '2013-10-20'),
('schoolvakanties', 'heel Nederland', '2013-12-20', '2014-01-05'),
('schoolvakanties', 'zuid', '2014-02-14', '2014-02-23'),
('schoolvakanties', 'heel Nederland', '2014-04-25', '2014-05-05'),
('schoolvakanties', 'zuid', '2014-07-11', '2014-08-24'),
('schoolvakanties', 'zuid', '2014-10-17', '2014-10-26'),
('schoolvakanties', 'heel Nederland', '2014-12-19', '2015-01-04'),
('schoolvakanties', 'zuid', '2015-02-13', '2015-02-22'),`

**Note that this is not all of the data but only the first 8 rows**

Now when I fill the table with data from the LOCAL xml file

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'absolute_path_to_file\\thevacation.xml' 
INTO TABLE vacations
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<vacation>'
```

I will get the following data in my table:

`('\r\nHerfstvakantie\r\n', 'zuid', '2013-10-11', '2013-10-20'),
('\r\n', 'heel Nederland', '2013-12-20', '2014-01-05'),
('\r\n', 'zuid', '2014-02-14', '2014-02-23'),
('\r\n', 'heel Nederland', '2014-04-25', '2014-05-05'),
('\r\n', 'zuid', '2014-07-11', '2014-08-24'),
('\r\n', 'zuid', '2014-10-17', '2014-10-26'),
('\r\n', 'heel Nederland', '2014-12-19', '2015-01-04'),
('\r\n', 'zuid', '2015-02-13', '2015-02-22'),
('\r\n', 'heel Nederland', '2015-05-01', '2015-05-10'),`

**Note that this is not all of the data but only the first 8 rows**

As you can see, when it takes the data from the LOCAL xml file it will take the type tag I specified, the one inside the  tags. But when I take the data from the ONLINE page it will just take the data from the first  tag it sees.

Can anybody explain to me why it does this, and how I can solve this problem. Because I would rather take the data from that webpage, not from a local file.

Thank you